# Unable to decode certificate Mono 6.4.0

Tags: c#, mono, raspbian, x509certificate

I am trying to get the certificate from a signed (exe) file. When I run code `X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(path)`, it returns the error:

> Unable to decode certificate.

In version 5 of mono it worked perfectly.

Comment: There are lots of different options and if nay are wrong you will get an error.  Here are some OF the errors 1) Wrong version of TLS (1.2 vs 1.3) 2) Wrong Options in VS x64, x86, x32 3) Wrong padding.  JSON and c# default to different options   For complete set of options see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: The file is signed correctly. This command on Windows works perfectly and worked on mono.

Comment: So use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare 1st request in working against your current code then make you code look exactly like the working code.  The default headers in Net are different from other applications.  I not saying the certificate is bad, just your options in c# are not matching the encryption mode of the certificate.  Windows is very smart and reads all the properties in the certificate to determine encryption mode.  Your c# is just settings one set of options without reading the certificate.